React Native with Expo and adding folders to iOS
In React Native with Expo, can you include a folder in the iOS build thru configuration without having to update the iOS project directly?  The folder I want to add has various binary and text files in it.  Also, I want to add the folder as a whole, not just individual files, such that if a new file is added to the folder it will automatically be pulled into the next iOS build.  This should be equivalent to adding a folder reference in Xcode.
